# RegOpenKeyEx returns error 161

Tags: c#

i'm having difficulty to rename one key of my registry. I dont know but all the time change the name so i was trying to use a program to do automatically. The code is the follow:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly IntPtr HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = new IntPtr(-2147483646);
        [DllImport("advapi32")]
        public static extern int RegRenameKey(SafeRegistryHandle hKey, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string oldname,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string newname);
        [DllImport("Advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "RegOpenKeyExW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int RegOpenKeyEx(IntPtr hKey, [In] string lpSubKey, int ulOptions, int samDesired, out IntPtr phkResult);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        { //mhmmm si, todo esta bien , bueno ire a ver lo que iba oka  ver
            ///Estas intentando renombrar una clave de registro una la crpeta que la contiene...
            IntPtr result;

            SafeRegistryHandle hKey = null;//no es necesario, esta funcuonando, si no, no me hubiere retorando un int
            hKey = new SafeRegistryHandle(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,true);
            int resul = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "\\SOFTWARE\\Company", 0,0,out result);
            Console.WriteLine(resul);
            int rosul = RegRenameKey(hKey, "SOFTWARE\\Company\\", "SOFTWARE\\Editado\\");
            Console.WriteLine(rosul);
            Console.ReadLine(); //Ok a ver dejamever unos ejemplos de advapi, los tienes ahi? mierdaaa no tiees ideas de los peos que se acaba de tirar mi perro

        }

    }
}
```

The problem is when i open the key:

```
int resul = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "\\SOFTWARE\\Company", 0,0,out result);
```

For some reason i'm not opening well the key. The error's return me:

[image: errors]

My regedit rule is not renamed:

[image: capture of my key]

Article that i took like reference:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2015/09/29/regrenamekey-hidden-registry-api/

I hope someone helps... It's for my computer only.

Comment: Note that if you are on a 64-bit OS, your screenshot is showing the 64-bit registry hive, not the 32-bit. .NET will normally redirect your access based on your applications bitness, but in this case since you are accessing the Win32 API so you may need to pass `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` or `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag.

Answer (score 3):

Error 87 is `ERROR_BAD_PARAMETER` which indicates that one or more of the parameters you pass to the function is incorrect.

Error 161 is `ERROR_BAD_PATHNAME` which indicates that you've passed an incorrect path to the function.

I think both errors are caused because you're using either leading or trailing slashes in your paths. So instead of for example `\\SOFTWARE\\Company` you would have `SOFTWARE\\Company`. Try the below changes and see if it works.

Removed leading slashes:

```
int resul = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Company", 0,0,out result);
```

Removed trailing slashes:

```
int rosul = RegRenameKey(hKey, "SOFTWARE\\Company", "SOFTWARE\\Editado");
```

**References**

- [**System Error Codes (0-499)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx)